# Xamarin forms: strange behaviour with a function that returns Xamarin.Forms.Color

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a strange problem with a function that returns Color (Xamarin.Forms). My idea is to show a box with different background depends on the `AppointmentStatus`. I created an extension for an enum like this

```cs
public static Color ColorForStatus(this AppointmentStatus status)
{
    Color rtn = Color.Transparent;

    switch (status)
    {
        case AppointmentStatus.Active:
            rtn = Color.FromHex("#654BE");
            break;
        case AppointmentStatus.Cancelled:
            rtn = Color.FromHex("#E14063");
            break;
        case AppointmentStatus.Completed:
            rtn = Color.FromHex("#C4E7EE");
            break;
        case AppointmentStatus.Hold:
            rtn = Color.FromHex("#84CEDD");
            break;
        case AppointmentStatus.InProgress:
            rtn = Color.FromHex("#B1D1DE");
            break;
        case AppointmentStatus.Paused:
            rtn = Color.FromHex("#F1E19E");
            break;
        default:
            rtn = Color.Transparent;
            break;
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

If I call this function `rtn` has the color I expected but on the screen I can't see any color. To try to fix it, then I created a function with similar code

```cs
public static class ColourHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determine the color for an appointment status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status">The status.</param>
    /// <returns>Color.</returns>
    public static Color ColorForStatus(this AppointmentStatus status)
    {
        Color rtn = Color.Transparent;

        switch (status)
        {
            case AppointmentStatus.Active:
                rtn = Color.FromHex("#654BE");
                break;
            case AppointmentStatus.Cancelled:
                rtn = Color.FromHex("#E14063");
                break;
            case AppointmentStatus.Completed:
                rtn = Color.FromHex("#C4E7EE");
                break;
            case AppointmentStatus.Hold:
                rtn = Color.FromHex("#84CEDD");
                break;
            case AppointmentStatus.InProgress:
                rtn = Color.FromHex("#B1D1DE");
                break;
            case AppointmentStatus.Paused:
                rtn = Color.FromHex("#F1E19E");
                break;
            default:
                rtn = Color.Transparent;
                break;
        }

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

And also in this case the result is the same. If I check the value in Visual Studio, the value seems correct but the function is `unknown identifier`. See the image.

[image: What?]

If in the main I'm using the same switch, I can see the colour in the screen as you can see in the picture below.

[image: Screen]

I call this function in a ViewModel.

```cs
public override async void LoadData(string search = "")
{
    AppointmentList = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(
                                       repo.GetAppointments().ToList());

    foreach (Appointment app in AppointmentList)
    {
        // this is working (it's the background of "Work" frame)
        switch (app.AppointmentType)
        {
            case AppointmentType.Quote:
                app.BoxColor = Settings.BoxColorQuoteSettings;
                break;
            default:
                app.BoxColor = Settings.BoxColorJobSettings;
                break;
        }

        // they don't work
        app.StatusColor = app.Status.StatusColor(); // with extensions
        app.StatusColor = ColourHelpers.ColorForStatus(app.Status); // with function

        // this is working
        app.StatusColor = Settings.BoxColorJobSettings;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I print in the `Debug window` the value of `app.StatusColor` and see the result I expect.

[image: Debug window]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post code of whole main function and how do you call it?

Comment: The main function is quite complex. I have a ViewModel there. I'll publish just the piece of code where I call it.

Comment: Add `Debug.WriteLine($"Color {ColourHelpers.ColorForStatus(app.Status)}" );` and see what it prints. I think it returns `Transparent`.

Comment: I did that and I see in the `Debug Window` the color I expected. I'll add in the question this screen.

Comment: `A=0`, if `A` is Alpha channel, so you are getting transparent color

Comment: Ah! How can I fix it? The problem is only there. If I use `Settings.BoxColorQuoteSettings` it's working

Comment: Try change `"#654BE"` to `#FF654BE`

Comment: The funny thing is I copied my code from another app where it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding alpha channel value to each color should fix the problem, for instance:

was `#654BE`, should be `#FF654BE`

Comment: `Color.FromHex()` sets the opacity to `ff` if it's not specified.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix interesting why `A=0`, would you know?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in this line

```cs
rtn = Color.FromHex("#654BE");
```

You're passing a 5 char long (without the '#') to `FromHex` and that's not a required format. The result is then undefined.

`Color.FromHex()` factory method expects one of the following format:

- `rgb`
- `rrggbb`
- `argb`
- `aarrggbb`

With an optional leading `#`.

In your case, the input string `654BE` is converted to the uint value `414910`, which is then split to RGBA values with the following `int` values (respectively): 6, 84, 190, 0. The Alpha channel being 0 is the reason why your color doesn't appear.